# How to find column names of a table where column is not null

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a **MySQL** table named `users` and it has `n` nullable columns and `x` rows.

I need to get the names of the columns if any of the rows have a value in that column.

Example:

**users Table**

```php
-----------------------------------------------
| id | ref | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
-----------------------------------------------
| 01 | 100 | null | null | null | null | null |
-----------------------------------------------
| 02 | 100 | qwer | null | null | null | null |
-----------------------------------------------
| 03 | 100 | qwer | plod | null | null | null |
-----------------------------------------------
| 04 | 100 | trye | qwer | plod | null | null |
-----------------------------------------------
| 05 | 101 | plod | trye | qwer | null | trye |
-----------------------------------------------
```

In this table column `col4` doesn't have a value in any rows. So when getting the column names,I need to **exclude** that column name.

desired output:

> id, ref, col1, col2, col3, col5

Some queries I have tried, but has syntax errors:

```sql
#syntax error
SHOW COLUMNS FROM `users` WHERE COLUMN is NOT null;
```

Another idea I have is that, find a row where there is minimum `null` columns.
(So it will be row with id `5` in the above table.)

Currently I am fetching all rows and process using PHP to get the results. Looking for a direct MySQL query.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT col_name FROM (
  SELECT 'col1' AS col_name, count(*) as amount FROM users WHERE col1 is not null
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'col2' AS col_name, count(*) as amount FROM users WHERE col2 is not null
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'col3' AS col_name, count(*) as amount FROM users WHERE col3 is not null
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'col4' AS col_name, count(*) as amount FROM users WHERE col4 is not null
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'col5' AS col_name, count(*) as amount FROM users WHERE col5 is not null
) colnames
WHERE colnames.amount > 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got a syntax error while running your query.

Comment: @iamab.in I've updated the query

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cte as(

select 
  count( case when id   is null then null else 1 end) as id
, count( case when ref  is null then null else 1 end) as ref
, count( case when col1 is null then null else 1 end) as col1
, count( case when col2 is null then null else 1 end) as col2
, count( case when col3 is null then null else 1 end) as col3
, count( case when col4 is null then null else 1 end) as col4
, count( case when col5 is null then null else 1 end) as col5
from table_name
)     select 'id  ' from cte where id  = 0 
union select 'ref ' from cte where ref = 0 
union select 'col1' from cte where col1 =0
union select 'col2' from cte where col2 =0
union select 'col3' from cte where col3 =0
union select 'col4' from cte where col4 =0
union select 'col5' from cte where col5 =0
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will test your method and will share the result